# nfs, mounted loop devices

Tags: nfs, export, loop-device

I'm usign a Debian server (Jessie) as an NFS server. All exported NFS-shares are mounted filesystems using loop devices. They are mounted in the fstab without any special options & the mountpoints are managed within a common root directory:

- `/nfsshares        *(rw,fsid=0,async)`
- `/nfsshares/mp1    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)`
- `/nfsshares/mp2    *(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)`

*mp1*,*mp2* are mountpoints for the loop devices!

Starting the nfs server causes an entry in the log file:
*/nfsshares/mp1* und */nfsshares/mp2* have same filehandle for * using first.

All NFS-clients always mount the first share - regardless of the used mount points. I think that this has something to do with the used loop-device for the mountpoints.

Isn't possible to use mounted images for NFS shares?

ThanX
/franzR

Comment: Can you clarify which version of NFS is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the locations of the directories being mounted, as well as client and server configurations it may be valuable to ensure that `/etc/exports` is setup correctly on the server.  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/how-to-properly-export-and-import-nfs-shares-that-have-subdirectories-as-mount-p) on setting up NFS with mount-points as sub-directories might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably a bit late to the party, but in the hopes of helping others with the same problem:

The problem is likely an identical fs UUID (at least it was for me).
Specifying a fsid in the export solved the issue. (Do note that fsid=0 is used for the 'full export', see https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports).

So adding fsids != 0 for the 2 loop devices exports should fix this issue. Result should look like:

```
`/nfsshares        *(rw,fsid=0,async)`
`/nfsshares/mp1    *(rw,fsid=1,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)`
`/nfsshares/mp2    *(rw,fsid=2,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,nohide)`
```

Got the inspiration from: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121743/different-loopback-mounted-volumes-exported-through-nfs-are-seen-as-1-by-the-cli)